# Sample Count: 1 Error Count: 1 Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text Response code: 500 Response message: Server Error

Tags: jmeter

I am getting `error 500`

When I am executing rest service uploading the `*.bdc` file in Jmeter.

While I am running the same service  file from postman give `success 200`.

**JMeter:**

[image: 1]

**Postman:**
[image: 2]

Comment: can you show your http request ? thx

Answer (score 0):

Check the header you are sending with your request.

Best way to debug this would be:

Use firebug or chrome developer tools, compare the request you are sending from JMeter and browser sends.
Check the headers that are being sent and other parameters being sent, accordingly fix your script.